# How to resolve async call within componentWillMount() before render()

Tags: typescript, react-native

Trying to figure out how to call async functions in `componentWillMount()` before the `render()` method is called. I have the following code (stripped down for simplicity's sake):

```
interface State {
    foo?: AClass
}
export class BClass extends React.Component<Props, State>
{
    async componentWillMount(){
        await this.run();
    }
    async run(){
        let a = await bar();
        this.setState({foo: a});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> {this.state.foo == null ? "null" : this.state.foo.getText()} </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I've seen one potential fix involving adding a `loading` variable to `this.state`, but that doesn't really do much. I've also tried messing around with returning `Promise` and then doing `fooPromise.then((c)=>{this.setState({foo: a})});` but to no avail.

All this to ask, is there a way I can call a blackbox async method within `componentWillMount()` and resolve the result before running `render()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make it render nothing until its done:

```
export class BClass extends React.Component<Props, State>
{
    state = {
      loaded: false,
    }
    async componentWillMount(){
        await this.run();
    }
    async run(){
        let a = await bar();
        this.setState({ foo: a, loaded: true });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.state.loaded &&
                  <Text> {this.state.foo == null ? "null" : this.state.foo.getText()} </Text>
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen one or two things using that technique, doesn't seem to work. The page renders blank, and just stays there indefinitely. I've seen `bar()` work before, so I doubt it's the method. Looking more into other sample async methods to confirm.

Comment: This was definitely the answer, `bar()` was acting screwy. Thanks a ton!